# How to debug a Realm memory leak in Instruments

Tags: swift, memory-leaks, realm, instruments

Realm is causing a memory leak in my app but Instruments doesn't provide much details about it, the Stack trace only showing 2 system methods. How could I track these leaks further ?

[image: al]